# PHP adjusting font size printing to network thermal printer

Tags: php, printing, epson, thermal-printer

I have the following code which works like a charm to print from PHP to my epson thermal printer. we use it to print customer orders in the office when they checkout on the website. I want to change the font size to make it look like a more genuine recipe.

Here is an example of the code i use:

```
$texttoprint = "RECIPT TEXT \n NEXT LINE \n MORE STUFF";
$texttoprint = stripslashes($texttoprint);

$fp = fsockopen("192.168.192.168", 9100, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
fwrite($fp, "\033\100");
$out = $texttoprint . "\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);
fwrite($fp, "\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\033\151\010\004\001");
fclose($fp);
}
```

If you can tell me how I can change the font size of a particulare line that would be amazing. thanks

From what I have read the 012/012 are ESC/p codes, here is a link to the manual - 
http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

But I dont understand how to apply this:

ESC E - SELECT BOLD FONT - C110

Answer:

Just for users who may need to know here is what you need, I found the answers in a python lib (http://code.google.com/p/python-escpos/downloads/list)

here is a list of how to do the ESC codes (found it in a python lib) http://sheepy121.webhost4life.com/ESC.txt

Here is the document for all ESC codes http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

and here is the code to use [PHP printing to local Thermal Printer, does not work without networkname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268479/php-printing-to-local-thermal-printer-does-not-work-without-networkname).

Happy printing

Comment: Sorry, this is a question to the printer file protocol, not PHP.

Comment: Ok, will update the tags, but as I am using PHP and someone out there most likely has done this before I will keep the php tag in as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a task for you to understand the manual. Not sure how you have done the rest before.

On page C3 of the manual you get a command overview. *ESC E* is the command to select a bold font (details on page C110). You want to change the font size so you need *ESC P*, *ESC M* or *ESC g*.

**ESC** stands for the escape character, decimal index 27 in ASCII table or hex 1B or octal 33. Place `"\033P"` within your string to try out as that is the way you include a special char with octal code in PHP [String manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: I did notice that where he uses \012 its for the decimal command for FF, or Form Feed. which you can see on page c-29. Where 12 is the decimal value for it under FF, but I dont know how to apply that to ESC and not FF

Comment: I did notice from ur link ESC is only supported in php5.4 wamp has 5.3 - start 100mb xampp download ...

Comment: Have you tried sending a pure textfile with the correct codes to the printer manually?

Comment: cant on windows cos the epson printer driver breaks any print job mid way. setting up a linux box now.

Comment: Find all the codes I need in a python lib and coupled with the document I can now see what structure is required to use them. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

use php print option. you can change font size and font family also..

here the sample php code...

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

$printer = "\\\\BALA\\EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt"; 

$handle = printer_open($printer);
printer_start_doc($handle,"Testpage");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 20, 10, 700, false, false, false, 0);
$pen = printer_create_pen(PRINTER_PEN_DOT, 1, "000000");
printer_select_pen($handle, $pen);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
printer_draw_text($handle, "welcome", 10, 10);

printer_delete_font($font);
printer_delete_pen($pen);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
```